# Processo Assíncrono em Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assincronismo

Tenho um processo que faz um *match* entre os itens[livros, filmes, musicas e jogos] de um determinado usuário no Facebook com os itens cadastrados na minha base. O problema é que o processo todo demora em torno de 18~25 segundos e não gostaria de deixar o usuário esperando esse tempo.
Estava pensando em assim que o usuário logar com a sua conta do Facebook, disparar tipo uma thread(nem sei se é possível em RoR) e redireciona-lo para o `root_path` e quando o processo terminasse apresentar em uma `div` alguma mensagem.

Como isto deve ser feito em Ruby On Rails, ou seja, há alguma gem para esse propósito ou alguma boa prática para isso?

Agradeço desde já..

Comment: Por que não usa ajax? Já é assíncrono (client-side), e no lado do servidor representa só mais uma requisição.

Comment: Eu poderia até usar Ajax, mas não sei como ele funciona quando acontece troca de paginas...

Answer (score 3):

Existem varias alternativas para processos em back end. De uma olhada no https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq acredito q deve resolver e enquanto o usuario espera vc faz chamadas em ajax p saber se a thread  ja foi concluida. Existem uma gem q so verifica os status do job no sidekiq

Answer (score 0):

Aqui uma lista das possíveis gems para isso:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs

Comment: @josuetex Por favor, tente elaborar melhor sua resposta. Embora ela possa ajudar quem fez a pergunta, respostas que contém somente links são complicadas porque a URL pode deixar de funcionar a qualquer momento. Se quiser entender um pouco melhor o motivo do que estou escrevendo acesse a questão do meta [*Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?*](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links)